# Nodejs alternatives to PHP's DOM and XPath

Tags: php, node.js, dom, xpath

Is there good alternatives to PHP's DOM and XPath in Node?

I had a look around and it seems DOM and XPath is there and can be installed via NPM package manager but wasn't sure if they are correct ones to be used for parsing HTML and XML?

Comment: No, there isn't really a "*correct*" one. NodeJS' core APIs don't include support for parsing and querying markup, so you'll have to find a [package](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/dom) you like. Note that some are and/or use native addons, which will require having [`node-gyp`](https://npmjs.org/package/node-gyp) installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About XPath I'm not sure, but for HTML, you can surely use [cheerio](http://npmjs.org/package/cheerio):

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var $ = cheerio.load(theHTML);
if ($(".my-class").is("#my-id")) {
   console.log("Yay, this element was found!");
}
```

It has the same syntax as jQuery - so, if you do already know how to jQuery, you'll know how to use cheerio.
As a bonus, cheerio works on Windows. JSDOM, which is the base for a lot of others HTML/XML parsers, doesn't.